# Macro to Hide/Unhide Columns in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I created a simple macro to hide/unhide columns in Excel (attached below).
It works fine, however, when adding a column within the range of columns in the macro, the last column supposed to be hidden remains unhidden.
To make myself clear: The range of columns in macro is AM:BF. When I need to add a column within this range, the column BG (formerly BF) stays unhidden. Could you help me how to improve the code so that the initial range of columns would stay hidden as well as the added one?

```
With Columns("AM:BF")
    If .EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
End With
```

Comment: You've stated “To make myself clear: The range of columns in macro is AM:BF. When I need to add a column within this range, the column BF stays unhidden.”, but this seems to be a typo? If you hard-code the range AM:BF in VBA, then add a column within this range, then *SURELY* it is column BG which remains unhidden, not column BF. Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have a placer for the column. You could used a named range along the top row of columns AM:BF (Which will then change if you add a column in the middle of it). Your code could then look like

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Range("NamedRange").EntireColumn
    .Hidden = Not .Hidden   
End With
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solves a problem when adding a column within the range. But if a column is added at the borders of the named range, it doesn't belong to the named range and, of course, doesn't hide/unhide.
Do you know if there's a solution for that? For example, I need to add a column at the end of the named range (in this case it's BF), but when added it doesn't belong to the named range and, of course, doesn't hide when using a macro.

Comment: Will the column always contain content and is it the last populated column in the entire sheet?