# VBA - How to unhide columns?

Tags: excel, vba

### UPDATE: So I found the issue. The macro runs when the user selects a link on the worksheet. I had the link set up to the unhide rows macro.

I'm having an issue unhiding columns using VBA. I've been using this link as a basis to try solving my issue, but it isn't working for me.

[Macro to Hide/Unhide Columns in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981782/macro-to-hide-unhide-columns-in-excel)

This is my code right now:

```
Public Sub a_view_calc_columns()
     Dim calc as Worksheet
     Dim rng as Range

     Set calc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calc")
     Set rng = calc.Range("A:T")

     rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

I've also tried:

```
rng.Column.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

And

```
With Columns("A:T")
     If .EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
          .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
     End If
End With
```

I'm using Excel 2016.

I should note that there will be data in columns A:T and that I'm manually hiding columns G & H to test the code.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what is happening with the code above?

Comment: Here is some info https://powerspreadsheets.com/hide-unhide-rows-columns/

Comment: I'm trying to unhide the columns with VBA. Nothing happens with any of the code I'm running. I have a msg box that pops up at the end of the code and says "Successful." That's the only thing that happens when I run it.

Comment: Which columns are you trying to unhide? Are they hidden? And where is the message box in the above code?

Comment: try `rng.ColumnWidth = 8`

Comment: Thanks QHarr for the link but I've already checked that link out. I've actually been working on figuring this out the past two days.

Comment: QHarr, check the end of question. I'm manually hiding columns G & H and trying code that will unhide them. I didn't put in the msg box code because it's unnecessary.

Comment: @Jeeped, I tried it, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet
        If .Columns("G:H").EntireColumn.Hidden Then
            MsgBox "Hidden"
            .Columns("G:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Else
           MsgBox "Those columns aren't hidden"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, So I found the issue. The macro runs by the user selecting a link on the worksheet. I had the link set up to the unhide rows macro. Thanks for your help because your test is actually what allowed me to realize that.

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)